# How to write well-balanced conclusions? To re-describe findings, make statement, make implication?

Tags: thesis, conclusion-section

Conclusions are so important. However, there seem to be many ways of writing them. How to write well-balanced conclusions? I give a simple made-up example. The example simply says that care was inaccessible for patients and 20-year temporal trends showed marginal improvement.

**AIM**

Describe/assess patients care during 2000-2020 in a country.

**RESULTS**

1. 70% of patients received no treatment despite needing it.
2. During the 20-year period, the probability of receiving treatment increased only by 5 percentage points [95 CI: 2.4; 8.1]; however, only 33% of patients received treatment at the end of the observed period.

**CONCLUSION OPTIONS**

**A) I can re-describe the findings but this does not seem like a statement. However, it seems a really safe (hard to argue) option.**

*Most of the patients received no care during 2000-2020. Despite the probability of receiving treatment increased during the observed period, two-thirds of the patients still received no treatment in 2020.*

**B) I can state something to say was these patients' management good or bad but this says less about the situation.**

*These patients care conflicted with multiple international guidelines as patients often received no treatment during the 20-year period.*

**C) I can say what needs to be done but this is more like an implication.**

*There is a need to review particular healthcare resources to ensure care for this patient population, as they were mostly excluded from recommended care.*

**D) Your option?**

Comment: I think this is too based on opinion and specific circumstances to be answered generally.

Comment: What do other articles in the journals you submit to do? They will provide models for you to modify.